# How can I resolve dependency in Castle Windsor Factory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, factory-pattern

I read about factories in CastleWindsor but I cannot get it clear. Hope anyone could help me.
I have this typed factory in an MVC4 project.

```
public interface IOrderProcessorFactory
{
    T Create<T>(string ProcessorName) where T : IOrderProcessor;

    void Release(object service);

    IOrderProcessor GetTakeAway();
    IOrderProcessor GetInLocal();

}
```

this is register this way:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IOrderProcessorFactory>).AsFactory();   

container.Register(Component.For<IOrderProcessor>).ImplementedBy<TakeAwayOrderProcessor>().LifestylePerWebRequest().Named("TakeAway"));

container.Register(Component.For<IOrderProcessor>().ImplementedBy<InLocalOrderProcessor>().LifestylePerWebRequest().Named("InLocal"));
```

If inside an MVC controller I call the factory in this way.

```
_orderProcessorFactory.GetTakeAway();
```

I get the correct one, the one named "TakeAway".
But for this I have to previous know the type. In other words, I want to call the factory get methods and pass a "name" and the factory returns the correct one.

For example in pseudo-code I want this

```
TakeAwayOrderProcessor processor1 = factory.GetMeProcessorCalled("TakeAway")
InLocalOrderProcessor processor2 = factory.GetMeProcessorCalled("InLocal")
```

I know I can pass parameters to the constructor but then I will have to select it "manually" with if name is this return this one else...

Is there any way Windsor can do this automatic, like StructureMap do with:

```
ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IOrderProcessor>("InLocal");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [TypedFactoryComponentSelector](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx?HL=typedfactory#Custom_ITypedFactoryComponentSelector_s_15)